# searching for field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a JSON document which resembles this

```
{"type":"line","line_id":89522,"play_name":"Taming of the Shrew","speech_number":19,"line_number":"2.1.58","speaker":"PETRUCHIO","text_entry":"To instruct her fully in those sciences,"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_id":89522}}
{"type":"line","line_id":89523,"play_name":"Taming of the Shrew","speech_number":19,"line_number":"2.1.59","speaker":"PETRUCHIO","text_entry":"Whereof I know she is not ignorant:"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_id":89523}}
{"type":"line","line_id":89524,"play_name":"Taming Day","speech_number":19,"line_number":"2.1.60","speaker":"PETRUCHIO","text_entry":"Accept of him, or else you do me wrong:"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_id":89524}}
```

I am trying to do a search on play_name that it will return as long as play_name contains "Taming".

My query is like this

```
GET /shakespeare/doc/_search
{
  "query":{
    "match":{"play_name":"Taming"}
  }

}
```

HOwever, the things is that it doesnt return all the results where the play_name contains Taming.  I read the docs and it seems this should work. Hence can anyone tell mw what I am doing wrong?

PS :this is my mapping settings

```
{
  "shakespeare": {
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "line_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "line_number": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "play_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "speaker": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "speech_number": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "text_entry": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Adam, can you please share your type mapping and index settings.

for mapping , run this command "GET /shakespeare/doc/_mapping"

,and for index settings. "GET /shakespeare/doc/_settings"

And, also, please share the document(s) which is not returned by your above match query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try like this:

```
"query": {
        "wildcard" : {
             "play_name":"*Taming*" 
           }
 }
```

Comment: Hello Green, I tried this too  but it didnt work too.

Comment: Before the edit it would work for the exact term **"Taming"** , when wildcard give you more flexibility

Answer (score 0):

You should change the mapping for the `play_name` field to `"type": "text"`. You can still include a keyword mapping if you plan on searching for exact matches.

The final mapping for `play_name` should look something like this:

```
      "play_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
```